# Is Pokémon Bank no longer usable?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, pokemon-bank, pokemon-ultra-sun-ultra-moon

I am trying to use Pokémon Bank on the 3DS to transfer Pokémon from Gen I VC and Gen V to Gen VII. I've never used it before and nothing about it seems to work as described on the internet:

- Poké Transporter is not available on the eShop and I can't figure out any way to download it.
- When I launch Pokémon Bank, it tells me there's no save data and asks me if I still want to transfer to Pokémon Home. The first time I said yes, it had me purchase a pass. Now when I say yes, it logs me in, then says I don't have any Pokémon to transfer and logs me back out.

As far as I can tell, Pokémon Bank now can only be used to transfer Pokémon that are *already in* Pokémon Bank to Pokémon Home, and has no other function. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Oh, figured it out. To actually get to a menu and be able to do anything useful (like download Poké Transporter), **you have to launch Pokémon Bank with a Generation VI or VII game cartridge inserted**. I was planning to start by transferring Pokémon from Gen V and had launched the app for the first time with a Gen V cartridge inserted.

Poké Transporter cannot be found by searching the eShop; it can *only* be downloaded from the Pokémon Bank menu while a Gen VI or Gen VII game is inserted.

1. Insert a Gen VI/VII cartridge
2. Launch Pokémon Bank
3. Buy the 1-year pass
4. Download Poké Transporter
5. Quit Pokémon Bank
6. Remove the game cartridge
7. Insert any DS-era cartridge you want to transfer (skip this step if transferring from a Virtual Console game)
8. Launch the game you want to transfer from, and move any Pokémon that you want to transfer into Box 1.
9. Save and quit.
10. Launch Poké Transporter
11. Select the game from step 7
12. Transfer the Pokémon from Box 1 into the Poké Transporter box
13. Quit Poké Transporter
14. Remove the DS-era cartridge (if applicable)
15. Insert the 3DS-era cartridge
16. Launch Pokémon Bank
17. Move the Pokémon from the Poké Transporter box to another Pokémon Bank box, or into a box in your 3DS-era game.
18. Repeat steps 6 - 17 until you've transferred all your Pokémon or are too exhausted to continue.